# Synapse pipeline - Extract actual filename from wildcard file path

Tags: azure-data-factory, wildcard, azure-synapse

We are getting a single file dropped at random weekly intervals into ADLG2 BLOB storage. The file format will be YYYYMMDD_WLS.csv. I am using a simple synapse pipeline with some data flows and copy operations. I have no problem picking up and ingesting the file using *WLS.csv in the dataset file path but when I pull the metadata itemName, it returns *WLS.csv and not the actual filename it processed like 20231220_WLS.csv. I need the original filename to be used later to copy it to an archive and append a post-processing timestamp. I also tried leaving the filename blank and returning childItems, but that returns a mess of additional characters even when there's only one file.

How can I retrieve the actual filename to then store in a parameter or variable to be used downstream?

Thanks in advance!

I saw another post that extracted the name using a bunch of nested REPLACE functions, but it's somewhat cumbersome to read and the client won't like it.

childItems output :

```
"variableName": "OriginalFileName",
"value": "[{\"name\":\"20231220_WLS.csv\",\"type\":\"File\"}]"
```

Comment: If you have the childItems (I assume from Get Metadata), that is an array. If you just want the first one, you can reference the first element like "[your_activity_name].childItems[0].Name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the file name using a wildcard path with the Get Metadata activity:

If you have a single file in your directory, you can follow the procedure below:

In the dataset, create a parameter named `fileName` with the expression `*WLS.csv` and use it as the filename with the dynamic expression `@dataset().fileName`, as shown below:

[image]

In the Get Metadata activity, create `child items` as field list as shown below:

[image]

You will get the Metadata activity output as below:

[image]

Add a Set Variable activity, create a string-type variable, and add the `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems[0].name` dynamic expression to get the file name.

[image]

You will get the output as shown below:

[image]

If you have multiple files in the directory, use the `ForEach` activity with sequential and the dynamic expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` for items to store the filename into a variable. Inside the `ForEach`, add a Set Variable activity, create a string-type variable, and add the `@item().Name` dynamic expression to get the file name.

[image]

Debug the pipeline, and every file name will be stored in a variable, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying this now and am running into an issue where if I specify dataset().filename (or anything) in the dataset file path, childItems is not an available option int the Metadata field list. It seems that childItems is only available when the filename is left blank. Any ideas why this might be happening?